# Rails 3 how to send parameters to nested object when calling as_json

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, json

I have a model setup like so:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to: media

  def as_json(options={})
    super(:include => :media)
  end
end

class Media < ActiveRecord::Base
  def media_func(some_param)
    ...
    some_val
  end

  def as_json(options={})
    output = super(:include => :media)
    output[:some_attr] = media_func(options[:some_param])
    output
  end
end
```

I have a controller like this:

```
class Api::FeedsController < ApplicationController
  def item_list
    @some_param = some_parameter
    @item_list = Item.all
    render :json => @item_list
  end
end
```

How the heck do I pass @some_param so that the media object receives it when rendering to json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this to the controller:

`render :json => @item_list.as_json(:some_param => @some_param)`

Edit. Added the method as_json to the object.

Comment: I don't know how this answer would even work. `@item_list` is an array, and arrays aren't methods and so this would be a syntax error.